# Decrease precision of float and int

Tags: python-3.x

From a large set of data, I would like to decrease the precision of each number, float or int (Python3) :

```
12345678 --> 12340000
1.2345678 --> 1.234
0.12345678 --> 0.1234
1.2345678e-05 --> 1.234e-05
```

But how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be to use log10 to detect the highest digit:

```
a=[12345678, 1.2345678, 0.12345678, 1.2345678e-05]
b=[math.pow(10,int(-math.log10(x))+4) for x in a]
c=[int(x*y)/y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

c is then equal `[12345000.0, 1.2345, 0.12345, 1.2345e-05]`

Comment: Good. I don't have quite the same results with my python version (c : `[12345000.0, 1.2345, 0.1234, 1.234e-05]`, but precision is enough for me (python 3.7.5rc1).

Comment: you can try with  `b=[math.pow(10,round(-math.log10(x))+4) for x in a]`